# Trying to use formatDate on datepicker

Tags: php, javascript, datepicker

I am trying to format a datepicker to have a specific format. The format I am looking for is ISO 8601 yy-mm-dd. Something is wrong inside $(function), but I'm not sure what.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Format date</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $jquery_css?>" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jquery?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jquery_ui?>"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', "datepicker");
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30"/></p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'})`

is the syntax you want

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-dateFormat

Answer (score -1):

If you're only using jQuery for this feature (and not for the larger framework), I'd skip the jquery and just use [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).

Comment: Obviously he wants a date picker. datejs is a validation and formatting script

Comment: He's trying to format, I'm offering him a way to do that. If he doesn't find it useful, no harm done.

Comment: There's no need to downvote answers just because you don't happen to like them.  You should reserve down-votes for things that are actually wrong, which my answer wasn't.  I am less and less inclined to answer questions because there's such a high chance that someone will down-vote because they don't happen to like my answer.  I'm sure I'm not the only person who feels this way, and you should know that you're contributing to this with your capricious and warrantless down-voting behavior. You should reconsider it.

Comment: I downvoted this because a) it did not seem to be an answer, just an opinion - hence better voiced in a comment and b) it did not answer the question. I rarely downvote, but this was just one of those days. I also commented on my downvoting, something that is even rarer to see here at SO